# fill a dictionary without using try except

Tags: python, dictionary, try-catch

Suppose I have dictionary and I want to fill that with some keys and values , first dictionary is empty and suppose I need this dictionary for a counter for example count some keys in a string I have this way:

```
myDic = {}
try :
    myDic[desiredKey] += 1
except KeyError:
    myDic[desiredKey] = 1
```

Or maybe some times values should be a list and I need to append some values to a list of values I have this way:

```
myDic = {}
try:
    myDic[desiredKey].append(desiredValue)
except KeyError:
    myDic[desiredKey] = []
    myDic[desiredKey].append(desiredValue)
```

Is there better alternarive for this works (both of them) that dont uses `try except` section?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `collections.defaultdict()` which allows you  to supply a   function that will be called each time a missing key is accessed.

And for your first example you can pass the `int` to it as the missing function which will be evaluated as 0 at first time that it gets accessed.

And for second one you can pass the `list`.

Example:

```
from collections import defaultdict 
my_dict = defaultdict(int)

>>> lst = [1,2,2,2,3] 
>>> for i in lst:
...      my_dict[i]+=1
... 
>>> 
>>> my_dict
defaultdict(<type 'int'>, {1: 1, 2: 3, 3: 1})
>>> my_dict = defaultdict(list)
>>> 
>>> for i,j in enumerate(lst):
...     my_dict[j].append(i)
... 
>>> my_dict
defaultdict(<type 'list'>, {1: [0], 2: [1, 2, 3], 3: [4]})
```

Comment: You should add a sample using the `list` default and also maybe mention that `int` default means default is 0 -- not obvious perhaps.

Comment: Is it possible to apply all dictionary methods to defaultdic ?

Comment: @Two-BitAlchemist Yes, Just added.

Comment: @Arman Indeed, it actually is a subclass of the built-in `dict` class and inherited all the dictionary attributes.

Answer (score 3):

I suggest `collections.defaultdict`

```
from collections import defaultdict
myDic = defaultdict(int)
myDic[key] = value
```

as Two-Bit Alchemist adequately put, the best thing about defaultdict is when you need multiple value keys(**without having to define** the value as a list first). Using `d["key"] = value` again would just reset the old value, So:

```
myDic = defaultdict(list)
for key in keys_list:
    myDic[key].append(value)
```

Comment: Do an example with this using the list one. That's where this solution really shines. (Also you might explain that `defaultdict(int)` means the default value is 0)

Answer (score 1):

The best way to do this is with python's excellent `in`:

```
myDic = {}
if desiredKey in myDict:
    myDic[desiredKey] += 1
else:
    myDic[desiredKey] = 1
```

Comment: To me this is no different than try/catch. It's just [LBYL instead of EAFP](http://www.oranlooney.com/lbyl-vs-eafp/), where EAFP is [usually preferred](http://stackoverflow.com/a/11360880/2588818) in Python.

Comment: @zondo: Although `get` can be handy it's actually not as efficient as Will's `in`-based approach. In my timeit tests, using `get` is about 40% slower, although that can be reduced to 20% by caching the `get` method.

Comment: @Two-BitAlchemist: EAFP is nice, and exceptions in Python are very efficient. However they are significantly slower than the equivalent `if`-based code if the exception is raised, although they are certainly faster when the exception isn't raised. Generally speaking, `try..except` will be faster only if the exception is raised less than 5-10% of the time.

Comment: @PM2Ring Sounds like micro-optimization on adding to a dict to me, but my comment was not meant to be about efficiency, just Python's typical style guidelines.

Comment: @Two-BitAlchemist: Exceptions are great when the condition is actually exceptional, but they are a major performance hit if they are raised too often. If speed is no concern then feel free to always use EAFP. Of course, if speed _is_ a concern, then maybe one should be using a compiled language, not Python. :)

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
myDic = {}
myDic['desiredKey'] = myDic.get('desiredKey', 0) + 1
```

And similar for your list case:

```
myDic = {}
myDic['desiredKey'] = myDic.get('desiredKey', []) + [desiredValue]
```

The `.get` method for a dict will return the value and default to `None` instead of throwing an exception. You can also specify the default return value as the second parameter `.get(key, default)`.